# My system hangs after error ethtool: page allocation failure: order:5, mode:0x12c0d0

Tags: linux, centos

I am suffering the trouble that my system hangs randomly with the errors page allocation failure, I am not able to ssh to it even if it is pingable, it will somehow recover a short while, below is the error message I get from journalctl, could anybody help to check what happened and how should I avoid this issue in furture?

```
 kernel: ethtool: page allocation failure: order:5, mode:0x12c0d0
 kernel: CPU: 72 PID: 160015 Comm: ethtool Tainted: G           OE K------------   3.10.0-693_151.tl2 #1
 kernel: Hardware name: New H3C Technologies Co., Ltd. UniServer R4900 G3/RS33M2C9SA, BIOS 2.00.52P21 11/
 kernel:  000000000012c0d0 0000000028da1f1a ffff8830def739c0 ffffffff816bfe10
 kernel:  ffff8830def73a50 ffffffff81197b90 0000000000000000 00000000ffffffff
 kernel:  ffffffffffffffe0 0012c0d000000000 ffff8830def73a20 0000000028da1f1a
 kernel: Call Trace:
 kernel:  [<ffffffff816bfe10>] dump_stack+0x19/0x1b
 kernel:  [<ffffffff81197b90>] warn_alloc_failed+0x110/0x180
 kernel:  [<ffffffff816bbd92>] __alloc_pages_slowpath+0x6b6/0x724
 kernel:  [<ffffffff8119c105>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x405/0x420
 kernel:  [<ffffffff811e11d8>] alloc_pages_current+0x98/0x110
 kernel:  [<ffffffff8119698e>] __get_free_pages+0xe/0x40
 kernel:  [<ffffffff811ecfae>] kmalloc_order_trace+0x2e/0xa0
 kernel:  [<ffffffff811f0b51>] __kmalloc+0x211/0x230
 kernel:  [<ffffffff815ab707>] dev_ethtool+0x8e7/0x1f00
 kernel:  [<ffffffff8119c105>] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x405/0x420
 kernel:  [<ffffffff8159e1c9>] ? dev_get_by_name_rcu+0x69/0x90
 kernel:  [<ffffffff815bd74f>] dev_ioctl+0x1cf/0x590
 kernel:  [<ffffffff815824cd>] sock_do_ioctl+0x4d/0x60
 kernel:  [<ffffffff81582be8>] sock_ioctl+0x1f8/0x2d0
 kernel:  [<ffffffff812280d0>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x350/0x560
 kernel:  [<ffffffff816cc141>] ? __do_page_fault+0x171/0x450
 kernel:  [<ffffffff81228381>] SyS_ioctl+0xa1/0xc0
 kernel:  [<ffffffff816d13fe>] tracesys+0xe3/0xe8
 kernel: Mem-Info:
 kernel: active_anon:7478458 inactive_anon:372091 isolated_anon:0
                                          active_file:38822 inactive_file:38913 isolated_file:31
                                          unevictable:7793 dirty:139 writeback:0 unstable:0
                                          slab_reclaimable:35889 slab_unreclaimable:94027
                                          mapped:1089128 shmem:1067200 pagetables:21990 bounce:0
                                          free:45167 free_pcp:0 free_cma:0
 kernel: Node 0 DMA free:15896kB min:0kB low:0kB high:0kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0
 kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 1345 16696 16696
 kernel: Node 0 DMA32 free:61712kB min:312kB low:388kB high:468kB active_anon:1237520kB inactive_anon:336
 kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 15350 15350
 kernel: Node 0 Normal free:44892kB min:44628kB low:55784kB high:66940kB active_anon:12160380kB inactive_
 kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
 kernel: Node 1 Normal free:58168kB min:45164kB low:56452kB high:67744kB active_anon:16515932kB inactive_
 kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
 kernel: Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 1*8kB (U) 1*16kB (U) 0*32kB 2*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024k
 kernel: Node 0 DMA32: 1063*4kB (UE) 547*8kB (UE) 204*16kB (UEM) 153*32kB (UEM) 88*64kB (UE) 45*128kB (UE
 kernel: Node 0 Normal: 2010*4kB (UEM) 3795*8kB (UEM) 486*16kB (UEM) 4*32kB (EM) 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0
 kernel: Node 1 Normal: 1664*4kB (UEM) 1296*8kB (UEM) 690*16kB (UEM) 909*32kB (UEM) 246*64kB (UEM) 16*128
 kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=171 hugepages_free=69 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
 kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
 kernel: Node 1 hugepages_total=171 hugepages_free=169 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
 kernel: Node 1 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
 kernel: 1145926 total pagecache pages
 kernel: 0 pages in swap cache
 kernel: Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
 kernel: Free swap  = 0kB
 kernel: Total swap = 0kB
 kernel: 100312735 pages RAM
 kernel: 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
 kernel: 1866404 pages reserved
 kernel: ethtool: page allocation failure: order:5, mode:0x12c0d0
 kernel: CPU: 72 PID: 160016 Comm: ethtool Tainted: G           OE K------------   3.10.0-693_151.tl2 #1
 kernel: Hardware name: New H3C Technologies Co., Ltd. UniServer R4900 G3/RS33M2C9SA, BIOS 2.00.52P21 11/
 kernel:  000000000012c0d0 000000000a368a25 ffff8830c676b9c0 ffffffff816bfe10
 kernel:  ffff8830c676ba50 ffffffff81197b90 0000000000000000 00000000ffffffff
 kernel:  ffffffffffffffe0 0012c0d000000000 ffff8830c676ba20 000000000a368a25
 kernel: Call Trace:
 kernel:  [<ffffffff816bfe10>] dump_stack+0x19/0x1b
 kernel:  [<ffffffff81197b90>] warn_alloc_failed+0x110/0x180
 kernel:  [<ffffffff816bbd92>] __alloc_pages_slowpath+0x6b6/0x724
 kernel:  [<ffffffff8119c105>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x405/0x420
 kernel:  [<ffffffff811e11d8>] alloc_pages_current+0x98/0x110
 kernel:  [<ffffffff8119698e>] __get_free_pages+0xe/0x40
 kernel:  [<ffffffff811ecfae>] kmalloc_order_trace+0x2e/0xa0
 kernel:  [<ffffffff811f0b51>] __kmalloc+0x211/0x230
 kernel:  [<ffffffff815ab707>] dev_ethtool+0x8e7/0x1f00
 kernel:  [<ffffffff8119c105>] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x405/0x420
 kernel:  [<ffffffff8159e1c9>] ? dev_get_by_name_rcu+0x69/0x90
 kernel:  [<ffffffff815bd74f>] dev_ioctl+0x1cf/0x590
 kernel:  [<ffffffff815824cd>] sock_do_ioctl+0x4d/0x60
 kernel:  [<ffffffff81582be8>] sock_ioctl+0x1f8/0x2d0
 kernel:  [<ffffffff812280d0>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x350/0x560
 kernel:  [<ffffffff816cc141>] ? __do_page_fault+0x171/0x450
 kernel:  [<ffffffff81228381>] SyS_ioctl+0xa1/0xc0
 kernel:  [<ffffffff816d13fe>] tracesys+0xe3/0xe8
 kernel: Mem-Info:
 kernel: active_anon:7478896 inactive_anon:372091 isolated_anon:0
                                          active_file:38822 inactive_file:38
```